# how to use SWC asset as FLEX component skin

Tags: apache-flex

Its been a couple years since I worked on Flex, but am now doing another Flex project, and am having trouble using a SWC symbol as the background/ skin for a button.

I *think* I want to use a SWC to store a bunch of image assets. I'd like to use them for icons, and ( what I am writing about now ) a background image for a button. I thought I used to use SWC files all the time to include image assets.

I have a symbol in this SWC that has scale9 defined, and I would like to use it as the background image for a button, but would settle for an HBox.

I have the swc set up with all the assets, have it referenced in my projects library build path, specified as a library under Library Compiler as -include-libraries myIncludedSwx.swc.

I can successfully add the assets to HBoxes now as:

```
import com.mySymbols.MySymbol;//The linked SWC asset 
var someIcon: MySymbol =  new MySymbol();
var iconWrapper : UIComponent = new UIComponent();
someFlexContainer.addChild( iconWrapper );
```

So, getting to the asset isnt a problem. But I cant figure out how to use it as a button skin, since its a movieClip.

This does not work:

```
<s:Button label="click" skinClass="com.mySymbols.MySymbol" />
```

The biggest thing I am trying to accomplish is get an image into Flex that has scale 9 defined, and use it as the background for things..  And I havent been able to figure that out using the SWC.

Any help is appreciated!

cheers-
Dustin

Comment: Sort the tags out - it cant be Flex 3, Flex 4 and Flex 4.5

Comment: I thought that, to access a symbol inside a SWC you had to embed the SWC.

Comment: @Reboog711 -  I think its embedded? Well, in the project properties, its set to be merged into the code. Is that wrong to do?

Comment: @DustinButler I'm not sure what project properties you are referring to. You have not provided code that shows an embedded asset. Something like this: `[Embed(source="path/mySWF.swf", symbol='symbolName')] protected var _embeddedAssetClass:Class;` . Then you can create an instance of it; add as a child or whatever else you need to do.  To prep the library asset for use in Flex you need to convert it using some Flash Pro plugin and then export the library asset.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you'll have to create a custom Button skin and add your background graphic in there.

Comment: I finally got it working two different ways. First one by pulling in symbols from a swc, where the symbol has scale 9 applied, and another where I defined the scale 9 in the css.  With the swc, I used CSS like  @Reboog711 mentions. With the png, I used this: http://rupnarayanb.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/mystery-of-scale-9-in-adobe-flex/#comment-95

Comment: @DustinButler Please post a formal answer to your own question; and mark it as such.  This will help others who have the same issue and come across this question.  I'm glad you have your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Though its not in a swc, but a swf. Thank you @Reboog711.  I had to use CSS to pull in the swc symbol, like this:

```
#btnBar {
            firstButtonStyleName: yellowPrefrencesBarButtons;
            buttonStyleName: yellowPrefrencesBarButtons;
            lastButtonStyleName: yellowPrefrencesBarButtons;
            color: #999999;
        }

        .yellowPrefrencesBarButtons {
            skin: Embed(source='/../assets/asset-library.swf', symbol='com.foo.bar.assets.yellow_button_down' );
        ...more skins...
        }
```

Alternatively, I found this link that describes defining scale 9 in the css, when using a png: http://rupnarayanb.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/mystery-of-scale-9-in-adobe-flex/#comment-95